# How to query Azure Blobs by modification date using azure-storage-node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-node-sdk

I'm using the Azure Blob Storage node library:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node

I've referred to this documentation:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage.md

I can do most blob operations just fine, but I'd like to list blobs that haven't been modified in a week.  The documentation is pretty light but there appears to be an access condition I can use, I'm just not sure of the syntax.  Here was my best guess:

```
var weekOld = new Date();
weekOld.setDate(weekOld.getDate() - 7);

var options = {accessConditions:{}};
options['accessConditions'][azure.BlobUtilities.AccessConditions.DATE_UNMODIFIED_SINCE] = weekOld;

blobSvc.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix('mycontainer', 'myprefix', null /*token*/, options, function(error, result, response){
    if(!error){
        result.entries.forEach(function(val, index, array){
            console.log(val.name);
            console.log(val.properties);
        });
    }
    console.log(response);
});
```

This pulls in all the blobs with the right prefix but ignores the modification date.  I'm taking a guess at the syntax of passing in accessConditions with my query so it's not surprising this isn't working.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `weekOld.setDate(weekOld.getDate() + 7);` sets the date to a week in the future, not a week in the past. Do you mean `weekOld.setDate(weekOld.getDate() - 7);` instead?

Comment: @Trott, good catch.  I had changed it to plus seven for testing purposes but, in either case, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to have server side filtering on the blobs using access conditions while listing blobs because [`List Blobs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135734.aspx) REST API operation doesn't support conditional headers. For the operations supporting conditional headers, please see [`Specifying Conditional Headers for Blob Service Operations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179371.aspx) (Section titled: `Operations Supporting Conditional Headers`).

Your best option would be to list the blobs and then do the filtering on the client side.